# jQuery, bug or something? addClass for selectmenu widget works only for the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to figure out if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong:
Adding a new class to the selector of selectmenu widgets

```
$(".select-cls").selectmenu()
   .selectmenu( "widget" ).addClass("red-cls");
```

only select the first one.

Also tried the separate selector like this:

```
$(".select-cls").selectmenu("widget").addClass("red-cls");
```

getting the same results

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9qkvfm1n/4/)

Maybe there is another way to add class to every widget?

Comment: You can do it by adding it in  <select class="select-cls red-cls"> then it can added  selectmenu.

Comment: yeah thanks, as Joe mentioned I could use each function to iterate, Just curious why it returns one object :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below waits for the the DOM ready. That might not be needed. Some jquery methods only work on one element. This code loops through all the components and adds the class.

```
var selects = $(".select-cls").selectmenu({
  width: 75
});

// ready
$(function() {
  $.each(selects, function(i, element) {
    $(element).selectmenu('widget').addClass('red-cls');
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9qkvfm1n/10/

It's not a bug. The API says it return a single jQuery element.

You could also accomplish this in just CSS:

```
.select-cls + .ui-selectmenu-button {
  color: red;
}
```

Using [Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

Comment: thanks, this will help, I will use this instead. but anyway from the logic of jQuery my code should also work and can this be considered as a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

.selectmenu(arg) seems to return only one object.

Just iterate over all the jquery matches, e.g. like so:

```
$(".select-cls").each(function(i,m) {
    $(m).selectmenu("widget").addClass("red-cls"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript, that should work for you. You need to add all of them by selecting each. You can't add them with one class selector.

```
$(".select-cls").each(function(i, elem){
  $(elem).selectmenu({
    width: 75
  }).selectmenu("widget").addClass("red-cls");
});
```